# How to Mock self variable created in method

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I got stuck while writing unit test cases by mock function. I have a self variable created inside of the function, not by the init method. When I run the script, it throws an error.

`myFooFile.py`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def my_foo(self):
        self.MY_LIST = []
        self.generate_value()
        self.other_function()
        
    def generate_value(self):
        some_ops_value = 10
        return self.MY_LIST.append(some_ops_value)
```

I have `MY_LIST` variable created in `my_foo` method, not by the `__init__` method. I am collecting values by the `generate_value` method. When I try to create a test `generate_value` method, throws an error

> *AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'MY_LIST'.*

Not sure how to mock MY_LIST and get it worked

Below is my test script:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from myFooFile import Foo

class FooTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        
    def test_generate_value(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.foo.generate_value(), [10])
        
unittest.main()
```